# Win7 WinForm font does not support style "regular" error

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, windows-7, font-style

I have a WinForm app. There are some `Form`s in it, all of them are in english, just one `Form` is in persian. I have installed this app on various machines, but today, after installation, I have gotten an error telling me that:

> Font "B Koodak" does not support style "Regular".

I really do not remember that I have used this style in that form. I have checked them all they were all on "Bold".
I have also all the font on that form to another one and updated target machine, but the error still persists.
Just today I have installed this on six machines running different versions of Windows, but this error only came up on machines with Windows 7. On Windows 8 and Windows 10 there is no error and everything works fine.

I have also searched the web for this error - someone suggests to re-install the font. I tried that, but without success...

Error details are as below:

```
 See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

********** Exception Text **********
System.ArgumentException: Font 'B Koodak' does not support style 'Regular'.
   at System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont()
   at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
   at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(FontFamily family, Single emSize)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReportObjectStringConverter.ConvertStringToFont(String str)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReportObjectStringConverter.StringToObject2(String str, Type type)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReportObjectStringConverter.StringToObject(String str, Type type)
   at Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiSerializing.DeserializeObject(Object obj, StiPropertyInfoCollection props)
   at Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiSerializing.DeserializeObject(Object obj, StiPropertyInfoCollection props)
   at Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiSerializing.DeserializeObject(Object obj, StiPropertyInfoCollection props)
   at Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiSerializing.DeserializeObject(Object obj, StiPropertyInfoCollection props)
   at Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiSerializing.Deserialize(Object obj, Stream stream, String application)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.SaveLoad.StiXmlReportSLService.Load(StiReport report, Stream stream)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Load(StiReportSLService service, Stream stream)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Load(Stream stream)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.LoadFromString(String reportStr)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.LoadPackedReportFromString(String reportStr)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.set_ReportSource(String value)
   at Beta_Partlist_Generator.frmPriceList.InitializeComponent()
   at Beta_Partlist_Generator.frmPriceList..ctor()
   at Beta_Partlist_Generator.MainWin.btnPriceList_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
********** Loaded Assemblies **********
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
—------------------------------------—
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
—------------------------------------—
Beta Partlist Generator
    Assembly Version: 1.4.1.1
    Win32 Version: 1.4.1.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Beta%20Partlist%20Generator.exe
—------------------------------------—
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Data.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
—------------------------------------—
DevComponents.DotNetBar2
    Assembly Version: 10.4.0.1
    Win32 Version: 10.4.0.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/DevComponents.DotNetBar2.DLL
—------------------------------------—
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
—------------------------------------—
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
—------------------------------------—
System.Runtime.Caching
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
—------------------------------------—
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2000.8 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.DLL
—------------------------------------—
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2000.8 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.DLL
—------------------------------------—
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2000.8 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.DLL
—------------------------------------—
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2000.8 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.DLL
—------------------------------------—
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.2000.8 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.DLL
—------------------------------------—
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1590.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
—------------------------------------—
Stimulsoft.Report
    Assembly Version: 2015.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2015.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Stimulsoft.Report.DLL
—------------------------------------—
Stimulsoft.Base
    Assembly Version: 2015.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2015.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/rep5/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/YPE25L3A.M0Y/C0HW6ZB7.A0G/beta..tion_1c5c6ab4a07f428e_0001.0004_ab8ae97963efb4e0/Stimulsoft.Base.DLL
—------------------------------------—

********** JIT Debugging **********
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: It seems the report which you are loading using `Stimulsoft` is source of the problem. Look at the report elements and check their fonts.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes that was the problem, i thought that because the report is not running at this stage it should not have such problem, but changing font style in Report to "Bold" solved this.